# SpriteKit - Creating scrolling background from very large image (640 x 6000)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I’ve successfully cut up my large image (640 x 6000) into 20 pieces, but can’t figure out what the best way to use these images is.

My only thought is to create 20 sprites and add them all on screen with the same moving action so they appear to scroll.

But won’t this just use the same amount of memory as loading the entire image into memory?

I’ve looked through the sprite kit docs but don’t understand how it’s done.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You would have the sprite be removed from parent at some chosen distance off of the screen and have a new one added at a distance off of the screen. I don't know if you are doing negative x scroll only, or x and y, etc. but the sprite kit demo project "adventure game" in the apple reference docs has a scrolling image system.

Comment: its negative y (from top to bottom) and as I said, the docs are confusing

Comment: You can download the adventure game project, no docs needed. :-)

Comment: I removed my answer, because it became too dependent on details I don't have and the texture limit of 2048x2048. My first question would be can you fit all 20 textures into memory at once ? If not, how many can you fit in at once ? I'd be leary of  loading 20 images if it's a continuously scrolling game like a vertical shooter. Are you solving a problem ? or was it an arbitrary thing to choose 20 files ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest skipping actions for scrolling and using update method instead. There is also a way to have only couple of background parts at the same time.

First, you need to create texture atlas and add all those images there.
Second, you need to create two properties in your scene:

```
SKSpriteNode *firstNode;
SKSpriteNode *secondNode;
```

I also suggest adding said atlas as instance variable, like
`SKTextureAtlas *atlas;`

In the init method of the scene or another setup method of yours, you need to create and position these nodes. Also don't forget to create the texture atlas variable before that.

```
self.firstNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:[self.atlas textureNamed:@"texture1"]];
self.secondNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:[self.atlas textureNamed:@"texture2"]];
```

Usually in such a situation I change anchor points of those sprite to CGPointMakeZero, to ease the calculations on positioning. This can be done like so:

```
self.firstNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
self.secondNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
```

It helps in a way that at (0,0) point of the sprite is the bottom left corner of the sprite.

So now we can add the sprite to our world, either directly to scene or to intermediate world node, as you like.

```
self.firstNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 0); // or CGPointZero
self.secondNode.position = CGPointMake(self.firstNode.size.width, 0);
```

Now we have two our nodes following each other.

How do we scroll? We need to change the update method. We need to create new property CFTimeInterval lastUpdate, we will need it to store the time that has passed since last update, and from that we can calculate the amount of pixels we need to move our nodes.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (!self.lastUpdate) {
        self.lastUpdate = currentTime;
        self.secondsCounter = 0;
        return;
    }

    double delta = currentTime - self.lastUpdate;
    self.lastUpdate = currentTime;

[self updateGroundScrollingWithDelta:delta];
}
```

And here is the method that actually scrolls nodes (you need some moveSpeed defined elsewhere or just change it to some constant):

```
    - (void)updateGroundScrollingWithDelta:(double)delta
    {

        self.firstNode.position = CGPointMake(self.firstNode.position.x - delta * moveSpeed, self.firstNode.position.y);
        self.secondNode.position = CGPointMake(self.secondNode.position.x - delta * moveSpeed, self.secondNode.position.y);

        if (self.firstNode.position.x < -self.firstNode.size.width) {

            self.firstNode.position = CGPointMake(self.secondNode.position.x + self.secondNode.size.width - 1, self.firstNode.position.y);

// here you need to change the texture of your node

        }

        if (self.secondNode.position.x < -self.secondNode.size.width) {

            self.secondNode.position = CGPointMake(self.firstNode.position.x + self.firstNode.size.width - 1, self.secondNode.position.y);

// here you need to change the texture of your node

        }
    }
```

In this method we move the nodes by certain amount of pixels, and then check - if the node is too far to the left, and is not visible, we attach the node to the end of another node, so our scrolling seems seamless.
Somewhere there you will need to change texture of your sprite, as noted in comments.
In order to keep track of textures I suggest making an instance variable `int counter`. Obviously it should start at 2, since we have textures number 0 and 1 already arranged on the two nodes.

You can use it to see what texture is next. So here I suggest a method to get next texture:

```
- (SKTexture *)nextBackgroundTexture
{
    NSString *nextName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myTexture%d", self.counter];
    self.counter++;
    return [self.atlas textureNamed:nextName];
}
```

So now you only need to update the counter when needed and swap the textures.
As I said you could place these lines in the commented parts of the method to scroll the nodes:

```
self.firstNode.texture = [self nextBackgroundTexture];
```

and

```
self.secondNode.texture = [self nextBackgroundTexture];
```

This way you will have only two textures in memory and scroll will work fine. (actually this is not true, since Sprite Kit caches the used textures, but hopefully it will free them some time in the future).

Hope this helped.

P.S. Actually after rereading your question I found that you need vertical scrolling, well changing this is fairly straightforward, you need to position nodes at start differently, use y coordinate and node height instead of width to find the positions.

Also on scrolling change Y value and not X value.

I leave this as exercise to you.

Comment: I feel bad telling you, but my image isn’t self repeating, each cut image is unique

Comment: I didn't tell that it is self repeating, ok, each image is unique, what is the problem?